# Perfecto - UFT integration

Tags: automated-tests, hp-uft

I have been learning perfecto mobile cloud through the self-guided online training offered by perfecto. Even I registered and used the trial period of two hours and got some hands-on experience.

Now I would like to get some hands-on with Perfecto-UFT integration. I understand that the free trial account does not qualify for accessing Perfecto from UFT.

But still I would like to know, is there any other way I could be able to work on Perfecto-UFT integration without a fee?

Answer (score 0):

You can not integrate both without paying for that.

You need to understand both the tools are proprietary and not open-sourced. So whenever you'll try to integrate them, it will try to validate the licenses and as you don't have it, you won't be able to integrate.

There are so many other features which are not available in free version. Check **[this](http://www.perfectomobile.com/pricing#package-comparison)** link for more info.